# Numpy matrix column not updating (Householder transformation)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a weird problem that i was trying to solve for hours. I'm implementing an algorithm for Householder transformation in numerical linear algebra. The detail of the algo is not important but I was stuck on numpy matrix update.

```
def householder_qr(A):
    """Householder QR Factorization
    
    """
    for k in range(0, min(A.shape[1], A.shape[0]-1)):
        alpha = -np.sign(A[k, k])*linalg.norm(A[k:, k], 2)
        print(alpha)
        # construct v vector
        a = A[:, k].copy() # a vector is [0 a_2] transpose
        a[:k] = 0
        print('a: ', a)
        print('--------------------------')
        v = a - alpha*np.eye(1, A.shape[0], k) # standard basis
        print('v: ', v)
        print('--------------------------')
        beta = np.inner(v, v)
        if beta == 0:
            continue
        for j in range(k, A.shape[1]):
            gamma = np.inner(v, A[:, j])
            t = A[:, j] - (2*gamma/beta)*v
            t = t.flatten())
            print(type(2*gamma/beta))
            print('A0: ', A[:, j] - (2*gamma/beta)*v)
            A[:, j] = A[:, j] - (2*gamma/beta)*v
        print('A: ', A)
        print('--------------------------')
```

All computation is correct except the last line where

```
A[:, j] = A[:, j] - (2*gamma/beta)*v
```

I'm trying to updating the input A in-place. So current column will be updated in inner loops each time. But my matrix columns got the right vector (`A[:, j] - (2*gamma/beta)*v`) but will not update.

I added many debugging prints. This is my first loop

```
-1.7320508075688772
a:  [ 1  0  0 -1 -1  0]
--------------------------
v:  [[ 2.73205081  0.          0.         -1.         -1.          0.        ]]
--------------------------
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
A0:  [[-1.73205081  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
A0:  [[ 0.57735027  1.          0.          0.78867513 -0.21132487 -1.        ]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
A0:  [[ 0.57735027  0.          1.         -0.21132487  0.78867513  1.        ]]
A:  [[-1  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  1]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  1]]
--------------------------
```

you see each time in inner loop A0 is been calculated corrected but A is not updated.

Input A is

```
A = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [-1, 1, 0],
              [-1, 0, 1],
              [0, -1, 1]])
```

I think it's something to do with if numpy.array has different shape on either side of assignment than it cannot update. But I tried to reshape a few time to match. Still can't make it work

Comment: `A` looks like it's an integer array, not a floating point array.  So your assignment to `A[:,j]` will downgrade everything to an integer.

Comment: @FrankYellin Wow you are totally correct. I changed A to float and it worked. Thank you very much :D